# How to correctly set up TestNG report parsing with Jenkins and Gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, testng

I am trying to get a Jenkins job to run that builds using Gradle and
runs tests using their Testng integration.

I have the latest Jenkins installed.

I have set up "Publish TestNG Results" and used the pattern
"**/test-results/TEST-*.xml" because I found that after a build I had
lots of files with paths like this one in my workspace:

workspace/de.lesspain/de.lesspain.scheduling/build/test-results/TEST-de.lesspain.scheduling.CronScheduleTest.xml

What my job reports is lots of the following:

```
    Processing '/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Mediatool-SSH/builds/2014-02-04_16-58-47/testng/testng-results-9.xml'
    Failed to parse XML: only 1.0 is supported as <?xml version not '1.1'
    (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <?xml version="1.1"... @1:19)
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only 1.0 is supported as <?xml
    version not '1.1' (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <?xml
    version="1.1"... @1:19)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseXmlDeclWithVersion(MXParser.java:2608)
```

First of all, which of the test result files are the correct ones that
should be parsed? The ones named testng-results* or
TEST-.xml?

Then I do not understand, why the pattern above matches in that case
and then why do I get this error messages when both types of xml files
generated by testng seem to be declared with xml version 1.1? Is there
currently a known problem with the combination of jenkins, gradle and
testng or am I just doing stuff wrong (probably)?

Thanks for any insight,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Found it with help by the Jenkins people. My gradle buildfile was incorrect in the sense that it generated JUnit test report xml files although it ran TestNG tests (I wasn't expecting that).

For those running into this, I changed the gradle buildfile like described here:

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_generate_testng_xml_report

and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It should be mentioned that Jenkins can archive the generated junit results just fine. You could have left your build alone and changed your job to archive junit results instead of testng results.

Comment: Good to know. Are there things I should consider, when deciding which form I choose? I just thought using the publisher native to the test framework would make sense without knowing if it actually has advantages.